Excel automatically create number based on criteria
enter image description hereI have three columns in an Excel spreadsheet. The first is a column that I am trying to make create correct numerical values depending on column B and C. The numbers in column A are in the format 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2. The first number is based on a lookup table for column B values. These numbers are static. The second number is based on values in Column C, and also on Column B. For example, if column B is A and column C is a, then the number should be 1.1 . My formula appears to work at the beginning, but if there are any duplicates, I want the number is column A to match the duplicate. In my example, I would like A7 = 2.1, A8 = 3.1, A10 = 6.1, A11 - 1.2 and A12 = 1.4. This is the formula I'm using with columns E and F being the lookup table.
=IF(B2<>"", VLOOKUP([@Area],'Document Request List'!$E$1:$F$15, 2, FALSE) & "." & COUNTIF($B$2:B2, B2), "")
I have tried Unique and Sequence as well. I can't figure out how to make the second number dependent on the entire column, not just the cell above it. Well, I think that's my problem.
In this image, Column A is what I want the numbers to be. enter image description here

So show examples of the values in cols B & C. Also, where does your formula reference col C?

I tried this formula as well and it gave me the same results: =IF(B7<>"", VLOOKUP([@Area],'Document Request List'!$E$1:$F$15, 2, FALSE) & "." & COUNTIFS($B$2:B7, B7, $C$2:C7, "<>" & ""), "")

The example screenshot doesn't show how column C affects column A. Can you clarify and provide a new screenshot?
As far as I can tell, the column A is only affected by column B.

That's my problem. I can't figure out how to make the second number in Column A work so that it is affected by column C and B. I went down the rabbit hole of combining columns B and C and finding unique numbers, but then the first number wasn't correct.

Can you create a new screenshot using static values of what you want the result to be? Be sure to include examples that shows  how columns B and C affect the result.

@AdamW., I inserted another image of what I need column A to look like. Every time I have a new value in column B and a new value in column C, I want the first number to look up from the EF Table, But the second number needs to start at '1' for the first instance a new value in B shows up. But, then the next unique value in column C (with the same B value), needs to be '2'.

Below is you the formula you can replace in cell A2. Explanation follows.
=CODE($B2)-64&"."&
LET(category,UNIQUE(FILTER($C$2:$C$12,$B$2:$B$12=B2)),
seq,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(category)),
array,HSTACK(category,seq),
VLOOKUP(C2,array,2,FALSE))

I am assuming that the letters of the alphabet in your lookup table corresponds to the nth letter of the alphabet, i.e. A = 1, B = 2, ... and Z = 26. If this assumption is correct, rather than using a lookup table, you can get the corresponding number using CODE - 64. In ASCII, the capital letter A = 65, so by deducting 64, you get A = 1.
LET allows you to build complex formulas by giving each piece of a formula a variable name that you can reference once or multiple times.
The UNIQUE and FILTER formula together gets a unique list of Category letters for each Area.
Then I get create a sequence of numbers and merge them using HSTACK creating what is essentially a lookup table, which I'm naming as array.
Then I use a VLOOKUP to array to get the 2nd number in your result.

Wow! That's great! Unfortunately, columns B and C will be text. Column B will be things like Finance, Sales, Human Resources. Column C will be open text that people will type into, things like Revenue, Policy, etc.. The numbers in column A will represent Folder numbers.

Column C being open text will cause issues. Does it have to be open text, or can you use data validation to ensure there's no typos or extra spaces that make column C no-uniform?

But regarding column B, you can replace the CODE() function with VLOOKUP.
